# Raise php memory_limit globally or only where needed?

Tags: php, magento, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have this Magento project running and encountered the well-known "Fatal" memory error. Until recently (after updating to 1.9.2.2 I guess), that project was running fine with an `ini_set('memory_limit','512M');`.

Most of the Magento stuff is still running ok with 512M, but there are some pages (especially configurable products), where all of a sudden more PHP memory ist needed. As I figured, some of them only run without `fatal` when memory_limit is set to 1.5Gig (!!!).

So I wrote a little scriptlet that is countig (harhar, using even more memory ;-) all available products options and based on the result is pseudo-dynamically setting a new memory_limit within that `configurable.phtml`-file.

**Is that a useful approach, or just a waste of time? Would it be better to just set it in `index.php` or `.htaccess`?**

I am using this approach to find out, where Magento needs more memory than the already assigned 512M and be able to then start digging deeper and answering the *Why?*. I was just wondering if this approach would make sense for future work. I'm not sure if PHP tends to use more memory (and therefore server RAM) than it actually needs, when it is allowed to.

Comment: it's just a limit. it's not "you MUST use this much ram". it's "you cannot use more than this"

Comment: It is not a bad idea to set the memory limit higher, especially when it is running on an application server, which is set up to run only PHP code. But I would also check, if you can find out why your script is taking up to 1.5 GB of memory.